# Share image on whatsapp using Selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to share an image on WhatsApp using selenium (java).

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[data-icon='clip']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/header/div[3]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/ul/li[1]")).sendKeys("C:/Users/ankush.kapoor/Desktop/Issue/CompassGroup/Capture.PNG");
```

I get this error from above code

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (1278,
>   29). Other element would receive the click: ...

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share any file try find below:

```
//To send attachments
//click to add
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[data-icon='clip']")).click();
//add file to send by file path
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']")).sendKeys("FilePath");
//click to send
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[data-icon='send-light']")).click();
```